# how to get opposite side of a foreign key relation in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following relationships:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def players(self):
         ????

class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="player")
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

From the team object, I would like to get all the players that belong to it.

How can I get the values in this opposite relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in some detail in the [documentation on following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Given a `Team` object `team`, you get the players with:

```
team.player_set.all()
```

You can override the `player_set` name by setting the related_name parameter in the `ForeignKey` definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this;

```
def players(self):
     return self.player.all()
```